# Adding a \vskip{1em} before each section - won't compile with it

Tags: sectioning

So here's the format I'm using for my sections (I have an article document):

```
\titleformat{\section}{\sffamily\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{\vskip 1em}{CHAPTER \thesection}{\break}{}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}
```

So every title looks like this, but centered and located one break from the top of the page:

> CHAPTER 1
>
> SECTION TITLE GOES RIGHT HERE

However,the code won't compile this way, and I have an error warning at every single `\section{title}` line. But the above is what it looks like in the live preview (I use Latexian). If I remove the `{\vskip 1em}`, then the error is gone, however, it the titles now look like this:

> ___CHAPTER 1
>
> SECTION TITLE GOES
>
> ______RIGHT HERE

Where the `_` are spaces. The "CHAPTER 1" is centered, and everything else is kinda stylishly shifted to the right. But, the code compiles.

There could be a much better way to do this too... my goal is for each section to say CHAPTER # on one line, then say the section title on the line below, all centered, 1em from the top of the page.

Also, while reproducing this to type this question up, I get mixed results. Sometimes the addition of the `vskip` causes a "1em" to appear in between the "1" and the "SECTION". Other times, after removal of the `vskip`, I still have a compile error and error warnings. Sometimes the text just completely flattens out into one line when I remove the `vskip`. Basically nothing is consistent and I'm really confused.

Answer (score 7):

First:

```
\titleformat{\section}[display]%
{\clearpage\sffamily\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{CHAPTER \thesection}{1em}{}[]
```

so don't use `\vskip` and remember the order of  arguments.

Here `1em` is vertical space between `CHAPTER \thesection` and title of section.

Second:

```
\titlespacing*{\section} {0pt}{1em}{2cm}
```

`1em` is what you need `2cm` is vertical space. after title you can change it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[display]%
{\clearpage\sffamily\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{CHAPTER \thesection}{1em}{}[]
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1em}{2cm}

\begin{document}
\section{SECTION TITLE GOES RIGHT HERE}
bla bla
\section{SECTION TITLE GOES RIGHT HERE}
bla bla

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Although, I need the 1em spacing (what you have set as 2cm) to be above the title, not below it. AKA I need the start of the title to be 1em below the top margin. I don't need the start of the text to be 1em below the title. I don't think I would use \titlespacing for that, would I?

Comment: Oops, I totally can change the pre-spacing with \titlespacing. Thanks again!

Comment: Ok, maybe I can't... Whenever I change the {1em} (the vertical spacing before the title argument), nothing happens, whether I do 1em, 0cm, 5in, 10 em, etc. Nothing changes... the {2 cm} argument does work if I change the value, however.

Comment: your right I'll see the `titlesec`'s doc. For now try `\titleformat{\section}[display]%
{\clearpage\null\vskip1em\sffamily\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{CHAPTER \thesection}{1em}{}[]`