# Section formatting messes up Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

So, a bit ago I asked a [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/265878/adding-a-vskip1em-before-each-section-wont-compile-with-it) regarding a specific format for my sections, which worked out great.

However, when I create my table of contents, it lists each section like this  : (without the ellipses though, I didn't know how to right align the pg numbers)

> 1 FIRST SECTION TITLE ...............................  1
>
> FIRST SECTION TITLE .................................. 1
>
> 2 SECOND SECTION TITLE ........................... 3
>
> SECOND SECTION TITLE ...............................4

And so on.

I also notice that the second section is listed on page 3 the first time, and page 4 the second time... In the actual document, the second section begins at the top of page 4 (I set each section to begin on a new page).

Basically, I'm wondering how to get rid of redundant `tableofcontents` entries. I want the name to include the number, but I also want it to be the right page number...

Also I need dotted lines between the section titles as well, not just subsections, although that's probably a much easier fix that I can google later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is `\clearpage` in `\titleformat`. Get rid of it. You can issue `\clearpage` before each section using `etoolbox` and its `\preto` macro. To put dotted lines, use `titletoc`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titleformat{\section}[display]%
{\sffamily\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{CHAPTER \thesection}{1em}{}[]
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1em}{2cm}

\titlecontents{section}
[1.5em] % ie, 1.5em (chapter) + 2.3em
{}
{\contentslabel{1.5em}}
{\hspace*{-1.5em}}
{\titlerule*[0.5pc]{.}\contentspage}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\section{\clearpage}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{SECTION TITLE GOES RIGHT HERE}
bla bla
\section{SECTION TITLE GOES RIGHT HERE}
bla bla

\end{document}
```

Comment: Worked great, thank you! Can I ask why this is an issue though? Just something from experience or what?

Comment: @Conor It is logic. You start the section, without typesetting anything issue a `\clearpage` and then typeset the section. So section starts in one page and ends in the other page. You have to pass `\clearpage` before starting the section to keep the section intact at one place.